# Can I knock myself prone? Do I have to spend any movement to do so?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, movement, monk, prone

I am building a Drunken Master monk, and came across this subclass feature:

> ***Leap to Your Feet.*** When you're prone, you can stand up by spending 5 feet of movement, rather than half your speed.

Since it doesn't cost much to stand up, can I knock myself prone to get protection from ranged attacks? If so, does that spend movement, or is it just free?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to gain the benefits of lying prone without incurring disadvantage on attacks? If so, is this broken?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/189107/is-it-possible-to-gain-the-benefits-of-lying-prone-without-incurring-disadvantag)

Comment: Related: [Can I make myself a more difficult target by flying prone?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/201637/23547)

Comment: @Kaia Not sure of the relative timing of your and Pepijn's answers, but citing the PHB made it a useful response to me, and I would have upvoted if I had seen it before deletion.

Comment: Semi-related: [Can you voluntarily drop prone if it is not your turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152346/33569), [Can a surprised creature fall prone voluntarily on their turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147699/33569)

Comment: I assume OP wishes to drop prone at the end of one's turn, and then stand up at the start of the next. Is this it? Might be on the question body.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

#### You can drop prone for free

From the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BeingProne) and [Player's Handbook (page 190)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#BeingProne) on being prone:

> You can drop prone without using any of your speed.