# Can I decide to lower my Initiative after rolling it in order to permanently change my position in the sequence of turns?

Tags: dnd-5e, readied-action, initiative

The current question is in some sense a follow-up to the following one:

[Can I delay my turn in D&D 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48222/can-i-delay-my-turn-in-dd-5e)

The answer to that question is **no**. The only means to acting at a different turn in the round than that which was assigned to you via Initiative rolls is the Ready action.

However, what if I decide right at the beginning of the encounter that I want to change the position of my turn **permanently**? Can I choose to lower my initiative? Is there any other way to achieve a similar effect?

Comment: Did you look at the two answers other than the top one on that linked question? Do they answer your question?

Comment: Specifically the other question asks "Has the delay rule to change initiative order been removed from 5th edition?" which seems exactly to be what you are asking. In previous editions, the Delay Action IIRC permanently delayed your initiative (just like you are asking about). None of the answer imply that they limited their scope to only temporary initiative changes either. So, I've marked this as a duplicate until we sort out exactly how these questions are different.

Comment: Also related: [Can you choose to delay rolling your initiative?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112516)

Comment: Note that getting a post marked as a duplicate is not a punishment or anything. In fact, it help searchers find our questions. All it does is prevent us from expending effort on the same question multiple times. Instead, we focus on improving old Q&As as needed if they are identical (as this seems to be). If you can make a compelling case for the question being different though, we can always reopen it.

Comment: Yes, I did look at these answers. But since I was not familiar with the exact content of the rule from earlier editions you've been referring to, it appeared to me that this particular question did not discuss *permanent* delay. In particular, all of the reasons given in the WotC-link in the second answer to not apply to this. That's why I thought it was worth asking for this specific detail.

Comment: @MarsPlastic It's not the answers that make the duplicate - it's the question. And these questions do appear to be identical.

Comment: @NautArch: As I said: Given that A) I was unfamiliar with the old rule, B) my particular question is not addressed explicitly, and C) the question has an accepted answer despite this, it was not unreasonable to assume this question was not the same as mine. In view of C), where is the right place to ask for that detail? In the comments of that answer?

Comment: @MarsPlastic No worries! We don't expect you to know everything, that is why we're here to help. We want to get you your answer. A comment would be a good way to indicate to an answer that a detail is missing that you would like added. I have given the question a bit of a polish to make it clearer what was being asked as well.

Comment: @MarsPlastic I actually gave the top answer a small edit too. Does that clarify anything for you?

Comment: @MattVincent Please don't answer in the comments. Use the comments only for suggesting improvements to the post or requesting clarification. Answers go in the answer section and if you can't answer because the question is closed, then try to help reopen it if you can. See [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments?r=SearchResults&s=2|51.4062) for our policy. Thanks!

Comment: @Rubiksmoose: Not worried at all. Just curious. ;-) Thanks for your edits, that *does* make it clearer. Logically speaking, this covers it all. Still, I keep thinking that it would make sense to offer a permanent shift of initiative at least at the beginning of one's very first turn (even if not any later)...

Comment: @MarsPlastic Such a rule (regarding shifting your initiative on the first turn) would almost certainly result in players deciding their "best" order and shifting down to achieve it in every combat, for instance deciding to all take their turns immediately after the character who usually knocks things prone.

Comment: @Speedkat: That's a good point. It would be easy to exploit such a rule in undesirable ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No

The post you have referenced explains the full scope of this issue, and there is no recourse to change your turn order after initiative is rolled.